# .Net WebBrowser.DocumentText Isn't Changing!

Tags: .net, html, browser

In my vb.net program, I am using a webbrowser to show the user an HTML preview.  I was previously hitting a server to grab the HTML, then returning on an asynchronous thread and raising an event to populate the WebBrowser.DocumentText with the HTML string I was returning.

Now I set it up to grab all of the information on the client, without ever having to hit the server, and I'm trying to raise the same event.  I watch the code go through, and it has the HTML string correct and everything, but when I try to do

```
browser.DocumentText = _emailHTML
```

the contents of DocumentText remain as "`<HTML></HTML>`"

I was just wondering why the DocumentText was not being set.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try the following:

```cs
browser.Navigate("about:blank");
HtmlDocument doc = browser.Document;
doc.Write(String.Empty);
browser.DocumentText = _emailHTML;
```

I've found that the `WebBrowser` control usually needs to be initialized to `about:blank` anyway. The same needs to be done between navigates to different types of content (like text/xml to text/html) because the renderer is different (mshtml for text/html, something else for text/xml).

**See Also**: [C# 2.0 WebBrowser control - bug in DocumentText?](https://web.archive.org/web/20200217201946/http://geekswithblogs.net/paulwhitblog/archive/2005/12/12/62961.aspx)

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Turns out I was able to get it with

browser.Document.OpenNew(True)

You're right - I needed to initialize it.

Comment: Why the doc.Write followed by DocumentText = ...? Isn't it enough just to do a browser.Document.Write(_emailHTML);?

Comment: Don't think this method works if `AllowNavigation` is set to false.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this issue for hours... Yet, I do not understand why the solution works. Could explain why doc.Write(...) needed?

Comment: It's been a few years since I worked with the browser control, but if I remember correctly, it was related to the initialization... it certainly isn't ideal, but neither is having to navigate to about:blank as part of initialization either. I'd recommend creating a method called "InitializeWebBrowser" or something so that the intent is clear.

Answer (score 39):

I found the following and it worked!

```
    webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
    webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(false);
    webBrowser.Document.Write(html);
    webBrowser.Refresh();
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. The only thing I was missing was the refresh.

Comment: Works like a charm ... even with the AllowNav = false

Comment: Unfortunately this will not raise the `DocumentCompleted` event.

Answer (score 11):

I found the best way to handle this, is as follows:

```
if (this.webBrowser1.Document == null)
{
    this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlSource;
}
else
{
    this.webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true);
    this.webBrowser1.Document.Write(htmlSource);
}
```

Comment: remember to put the Refresh() in the else block.

Answer (score 3):

That worked for me:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
webBrowser.Document?.Write(htmlString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you do not cancel *Navigating* event of *WebBrowser* for **about:blank** page. *WebBrowser* navigates to **about:blank** before setting *DocumentText*.
So if you want to handle links by yourself you need to create following handler of *Navigating* event:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Url.OriginalString.StartsWith("about:"))
    {
        return;
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just spotted this in some of our old code.

```
_webBrowser.DocumentText = builder.WriteToString( ... );

Application.DoEvents();
```

Apparently a DoEvents also kicks the browser into rendering

Comment: It isn't surprising that this might work, but I'd recommend avoiding using DoEvents when possible. It tells the message loop to stop everything and process all messages in the queue. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this answer [c# filenotfoundexception on webbrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737823/c-filenotfoundexception-on-webbrowser/4738244#4738244)

Answer (score 0):

While `Application.DoEvents()` fix it in a WinForms project, it was irrelevant in a WPF project.

I finally got it to work by using `webBrowser.Write( htmlContent )` (instead of `webBrowser.DocumentText = htmlContent`).

Answer (score 0):

**This always works**

```
using mshtml;


private IHTMLDocument2 Document
{
    get
    {
        if (Browser.Document != null)
        {
            return Browser.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
        }

        return null;
    }
}


if (Document == null)
{
    Browser.DocumentText = Contents;
}
else
{
    Document.body.innerHTML = Contents;
}
```