# C# Winform Webbrowser not updating after document text update

Tags: c#, winforms

Good Morning,

I have a Web browser embedded within a C# winform. When loading the web-browser, it loads in a local file and displays the page with no issues.

I then have a button with an OnClick method which does the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {      
      this.webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
      HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
      doc.Write(String.Empty);
      this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = //PathToDocumentText;
}
```

This was taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174403/net-webbrowser-documenttext-isnt-changing) and causes the web browser to freeze up. On hover shows the cursor with the loading spinning icon.

I am simply wanting to change the document text from one local file to another (both work if I load them in manually OnLoad).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
    this.webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(false);
    this.webBrowser1.Document.Write(//pathtoFile); 
    this.webBrowser1.Refresh();
```

This does the trick, Thanks to anyone who looked at this.