# Trying to use regex to replace text in a powershell script

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string that includes markdown text and I'm trying to convert it to html syntax. When I test in any regex tester, my code is good, but the powershell replace operator, just won't do it. I think I'm missing something, but not sure what.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Example:

```
$message = "This is a test: [Latest Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-218-update)"
$markdownLinkRegex = "/\[([^\[\]]+)\]\(([^\(\)]+)\)/g"
# have tried both of these options below
$htmlmessage = $message -replace ([regex]::Escape($markdownLinkRegex)), "<a href='$2'>$1</a>"
$htmlmessage = $message -replace $markdownLinkRegex, "<a href='$2'>$1</a>"
```

I have tried adding extra '\' into the regex string, but that made it worse.

I am expecting to see this result:

```
$htmlmessage = "This is a test: <a href='https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-218-update'>Latest Release Notes</a>"
```

Comment: Why don't you use an actual Markdown processor? Here's an existing question that may have answers for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460483/convert-markdown-to-html-in-net

Comment: `($message | ConvertFrom-Markdown).Html` would be most likely a better idea

Comment: In all my searching I never came across the ConvertFrom-Markdown command. Thanks. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility** Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/?view=powershell-7.2) comes with the [`ConvertFrom-Markdown` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-markdown?view=powershell-7.2) on PowerShell 7.2+ and it uses the [markdig library](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig) to parse markdown files and strings.

Converting your string to its HTML representation is as simple as:

```
$message = "This is a test: [Latest Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-218-update)"
(ConvertFrom-Markdown -InputObject $message).Html
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell doesn't use the same syntax as JavaScript so it doesn't need `/g`

Maybe removing the global do flag will work

```
$message = "This is a test: [Latest Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-218-update)"
$markdownLinkRegex = "\[([^\[\]]+)\]\(([^\(\)]+)\)"
$htmlmessage = $message -replace $markdownLinkRegex, "<a href='$2'>$1</a>"
```